Fill Smileys in Power BI with Colors by conditional formating
I am using the conditional formatting in Power BI based on other measure like below :

My goal is to fill the smileys with colors, but filling it with colors doesn't work.
The smileys I use have the following codes :  UNICHAR(128578), UNICHAR(128577) and UNICHAR(128528).
I get the smileys according to this dax measure :
Smiley_Conditionnel_t%rejet = 
VAR valeur = [Taux_rejet] 
RETURN
IF(
    ISBLANK(valeur),
    BLANK(),
    IF(
        valeur > 0,
        UNICHAR(128578), 
        IF(
            valeur < 0,
            UNICHAR(128577),  
            UNICHAR(128528) 
        )
    )
)

How can I fill my smileys with colors using conditional formatting ?

You just can't change the color of emojis glyphs, they are essentially images.
If you want to use those emojis and change the color, try use non-emoji characters.
Like: ︎ ︎ ☹︎
Instead of:  ️ ☹️
Result is like Test in PowerBI
And DAX:
Medida = 
var valor = SUMX(Tabela,Tabela[Coluna 1])
return IF(valor>3,"︎",IF(valor>2,"︎","☹︎"))

The conditional formatting can be just like you do, but with these new characters
